# Displaying custom fields with values

Tags: performance, php

How can I optimize and shorten this code that I am using to display Woocommerce custom fields?

```
function fields() {

global $product;

$value1 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'storage', true );
$value2 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'delivery_date', true );
$value3 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'mpn', true );
$value4 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'color', true );
$value5 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'sizes_available', true );
$value6 = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'country_of_origin', true );

if ( ! empty( $value1 ) ) {
echo '<div>Storage: '  . $value1 . '</div>';
}

if ( ! empty( $value2 ) ) {
echo '<div>Delivery: '  . $value2 . '</div>';
}

if ( ! empty( $value3 ) ) {
echo '<div>Manufacturer's product number: '  . $value3 . '</div>';
}

if ( ! empty( $value4 ) ) {
echo '<div>Color: '  . $value4 . '</div>';
}

if ( ! empty( $value5 ) ) {
echo '<div>Sizes: '  . $value5 . '</div>';
}

if ( ! empty( $value6 ) ) {
echo '<div>Country: '  . $value6 . '</div>';
}

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'fields', 10 );
```

There will be even more fields in the future so I would like to shorten it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify that most of the code contains repeated code, then isolate the few parts of the script that change.  These changing parts need to become variables in your new code.

There is a direct relationship between the generated values the labels that you displaying while echoing.  Create a lookup map/array containing these relationships.  As you iterate the map, put the variables through the same processes as in your original script.

```
$map = [
    'storage' => 'Storage',
    'delivery_date' => 'Delivery',
    'mpn' => "Manufacturer's product number",
    'color' => 'Color',
    'sizes_available' => 'Sizes',
    'country_of_origin' => 'Country'
];

foreach ($map as $column => $label) {
    $value = get_post_meta($product->id, $column, true);
    if ($value) {
        echo "<div>$label: $value</div>";
    }
}
```

Also, `!empty()` would be an appropriate truthy check on the data if the variables might not be declared.  Because you are unconditionally declaring the values, a simple/function-less truthy check will suffice.

Using a map is an ideal technique, because whenever you wish to extend/manage the columns in your output, you only need to adjust the map -- there is no need to touch the processing code inside the loop.

Disclaimer: I do not WordPress therefore I do not know if there is a more direct way to fetch all of the desired data without iterated calls of `get_post_meta()`.